# Hudson Shellscript for exporting Sourcecode from SVN repository into production folder

Tags: svn, hudson, lamp, production-environment

I have one dedicated server which has the whole Lamp-Stack, SVN and Hudson installed.
I would like to create a freestyle Hudson job, that gets the latest sourcecode out of my SVN-repository and puts it into my /var/www/myWebApp Folder.

How does the shell script need to look like?

**EDIT**

When I just use

```
svn export myRepoURL myWebAppFolder
```

i get an erro, stating:

```
Started by user anonymous
Reverting http://myIpAdress/repos
Updating http://myIpAdress/repos
At revision 2
no change for http://myIpAdress/repos since the previous build
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson7864414135197533508.sh
+ svn export http://myIpAdress/repos/myRepo
/var/www/myWebApp
Authentication realm: <http://myIpAdress> Subversion Repository
Password for 'hudson': Authentication realm: <http://myIpAdress> Subversion Repository
Username: svn: PROPFIND request failed on '/repos/myRepo'
svn: PROPFIND of '/repos/myRepo': authorization failed (http://myIpAdress)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should look something like below

> svn export [your svn URL] /var/www/myWebApp

Do let me know if I am  missing something here ?

Comment: Thank you very much, the upvots indicate that this is the right solution. But when I use your code I get an error. please respond to my edit.

Comment: The error is basically because while running the export command svn is looking for username and password. Subversion has the capability to store the password locally at its first operation. So to escape this you can do a dummy checkout (or similar operation) which will make subversion store the credentials locally.

Comment: @paskster: btw, you need to do this as the same user which you started hudson.

Answer (score 1):

I would also just run a copy. Make sure not to copy the .svn folders and other files that shouldn't be accessible from the outside world.

I also looked up the `svn export` command and it looks even better. If your job is setup to checkout from svn you can also run `svn export ${WORKSPACE}/* /var/www/myWebApp`. This will only copy files that are under source control. However, it will give you the option to change some configurations (that are important for the environment you are deploying too) before deploying it to your target.

Very important in any case, come up with a means to **check if it was successful**. So at least check the error code of all the commands that you run.

Answer (score 0):

Write a script to copy (using the 'cp' command) all of the files from the job's workspace to whatever location you want. You should make use of the 'WORKSPACE' environment variable provided by Hudson, which provides you the path to the job's workspace. The script will likely be able to run in whatever shell you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I think the previously mentioned `svn export` is the right solution, but if you're going to do a copy, I recommend something like `rsync` or `tar` over a bare cp. Both will allow you to exclude certain files or directories, refer to the `--exclude` command line option. (Googling for `tar exclude svn` will point you in the right direction.) [Rsync's advantage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) is that it will only copy changes, so the deployment is much quicker when only a small number of files have changed.

Other things to consider:

- You should have a plan for deleting files that are no longer part of the repository.
- You should consider how you will manage your web app's configuration. I don't recommend checking in a deployment configuration to subversion, especially if other developers need to make changes to this configuration in order to test locally. It's too easy for an accidental configuration change in subversion to break your production system.